# Completing a table with rows not existing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
buyer        product        quantity
tom          skirt          2
anna         skirt          3
tom          jeans          5
```

The `distinct(product) = skirt` and `jeans`

I want a table that inserts another column with `quantity = 0` when the `<buyer, product>` tuple does not exist for all possible products.

So the result would be:

```
buyer        product        quantity
tom          skirt          2
anna         skirt          3
tom          jeans          5
anna         jeans          0
```

It does not look very complicated but I don't know how to do it.

UPDATE
I have found one extra complication.

My product is actually defined by two fields: class and product. Product can be null and I need not to lose the information quantity when the product field is null (now it is happening with the cross join).

So if I have this:

```
buyer       class       product        quantity
tom         clothes     skirt          2
anna        clothes     skirt          3
tom         clothes     jeans          5
jim         shoes       NULL           7
```

I would need:

```
buyer       class       product        quantity
tom         clothes     skirt          2
anna        clothes     skirt          3
tom         clothes     jeans          5
anna        clothes     jeans          0
jim         shoes       NULL           7
jim         clothes     skirt          0
jim         clothes     jeans          0
tom         shoes       NULL           0
anna        shoes       NULL           0
```

Thank you all, I know I am complicating things!

Comment: You have also a table for the clients? what is the structure?

Comment: I dont but I could create a table of distinct buyer if needed.

Comment: Are there tables available with the full list of relevant values for buyer / class / product? And I assume each class that has no shall default  to one row with `product NULL` and `quantity 0`? Plus always provide your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: yes, there is a table of products. And yes, each class that has no shall default to one row with product NULL and quantity 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` to generate all possible combinations of buyers and products.  Then use a `left join` (or `not exists`) to filter out the ones already in the table:

```
insert into table(buyer, product, quantity)
    select b.buyer, p.product, 0
    from (select distinct buyer from table) b cross join
         (select distinct product p from table) p left join
         table t
         on t.buyer = b.buyer and t.product = p.product
    where t.buyer is null;
```

EDIT:

If you want a query that returns all the rows, then you would use something quite similar:

```
    select b.buyer, p.product, coalesce(t.qty, 0) as qty
    from (select distinct buyer from table) b cross join
         (select distinct product p from table) p left join
         table t
         on t.buyer = b.buyer and t.product = p.product;
```

EDIT II:

If you have `NULL` values for buyer and/or product, then use `NULL` safe comparisons:

```
    select b.buyer, p.product, coalesce(t.qty, 0) as qty
    from (select distinct buyer from table) b cross join
         (select distinct product p from table) p left join
         table t
         on t.buyer is not distinct from b.buyer and
            t.product is not distinct from p.product;
```

(As a minor side note:  I really do not like the use of `distinct` in this construct.  Why did Postgres (ANSI ?) give it such a complicated name?)

Comment: Almost. You have some errors. With that you only get the row that doesn't exists. edit like this:  select b.buyer, p.p, isnull(t.quantity,0)
  from (select distinct buyer from @tb) b cross join
   (select distinct product p from @tb) p left join
   @tb t
   on t.buyer = b.buyer and t.product = p.p

Comment: @bugs2919 . . . The OP only *want* rows that don't exist in the table.  Re-read the question.

Comment: I think no, it says 'So the result would be:' and is the full set.

Comment: But, nice answer. I haven´t had think on cross join. +1 greatings!

Comment: Hi, thank you to both. Would you also know the answer to the update in my question?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very much. Does it work for my new situation in which  product is no longer one field but it comes described by two fields: class and product. Plus any of them can be null. How would the query look?

Comment: @SiraRM . . . You should ask a new question as a *new* question, not as an update to an already answered question.  Updating a question so answers are invalidated is impolite -- because the answers can then draw downvotes.  I would suggest that you roll back the changes to the question and ask another question (you can reference this one).

Comment: I didnt know about that, sorry. I open a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297265/sql-adding-in-a-table-rows-that-dont-exist

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Gordon is almost full, I edit like this:

```
declare @tb table (buyer varchar(150), product varchar(150), quantity int)

insert into @tb 
values('tom','skirt',2),
('anna','skirt',3),
('tom','jeans',5)


select *
from @tb a
left join(  select 
        distinct(product) 
        from @tb) b on a.product = a.product

        select b.buyer, p.p, isnull(t.quantity,0)
        from (select distinct buyer from @tb) b cross join
            (select distinct product p from @tb) p left join
            @tb t
            on t.buyer = b.buyer and t.product = p.p
        --where t.buyer is null
```

Try it.

Comment: Using `@` in an identifier invalid (standard) SQL and won't work in Postgres. Btw: `distinct` is **not** a function. `distinct(product)` does not make sense.